# how to safely use ArrayList sublist to avoid first entry

Tags: java, android

i have an icky scenario where i have a dummy entry as the first entry of an ArrayList A and I need to pass in the rest of the entries into an adapter. (The dummy entry is a workaround for another scenario which i cannot avoid)

I'm adding and deleting entries from this ArrayList so i dont want  a "copy" of the ArrayList but the same one.

quite often the dummy entry would be the only entry in the ArrayList so how can i safely use sublist here . obviously A.sublist(1,lastIndex) is not going to work. Appreciate the response.

Comment: You should never need a dummy entry. Why do you do that?

Comment: Keep the dummy entry in a variable and pass the arrayList with out dummy entry. Or you can return count-1 in getCount method. And in getView the position used to get the items should be position + 1

Comment: I agree with @FD_ -  whatever problem you have that requires you to use a dummy entry, that's the one you should be asking about.

Comment: assuming the dummy entry is absolutely necessary, there's no reason that `subList(1, lastIndex)` wouldn't work, as stated by Teocali

Comment: ok my problem got solved with Rajesh CP's "count-1 in getCount method. And in getView the position used to get the items should be position + 1" , so i can avoid the sublist.

Answer (score 4):

> obviously A.sublist(1,lastIndex) is not going to work.

Yes, It will work. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29),

> The returned view will be of zero length if start equals end.

So, `A.sublist(1,lastIndex)` with 1 as lastIndex will return an empty list.

Comment: with just one entry (the one that i'm trying to avoid) the lastIndex is 0

Comment: If you have a A list with the content {d,1,2,3} and if you want only {1,2,3} in your sublist, you will use A.sublist(1,3) as the second argument is the last index of the list, exclusive, as said in the documentation.